# What does 1° mean?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, rotations

We all know and use degrees in real life, not just in math classes(even radians). We all know that π radians=180°,a full rotation of circle equals to 360°, degrees is a measurement unit of an angle and blablabla etc... But a basic question is what does 1° represent?To What it equals to? I mean why for example full rotation of a circle equals 360° and not some other number. How it is measured?

Comment: $1^\circ$ is _by definition_ the angle representing one 360th of the full rotation. The question is then "why 360?" and this is a good question. I don't know exact answer, but I'm sure it has something to do with 360 having a lot of factors.

Comment: Certainly not a "why" but another application of $360$: The Mayans used a modified base-$20$ system. But instead of $20^0,\ 20^1, 20^2$ etc, they used $18\cdot 20 = 360$ in place of $20^2$. So rather than $20^3$, they used $18 \cdot 20^2$ for example.

Comment: I heard somewhere it has to do with babylonian numerals, using the sexagesimal system. Of course the reason they used 60 is probably because also 60, and not just 360, has a lot of divisors. It sure is convenient though when teaching fractions that we have 60 minutes in an hour and 60 divides 360.

Answer (score 4):

I think we originally defined 1° to be the $1/360$ of a full circle, because this lets us divide the circle into many angles we use in the everyday life: $360 = 2^3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5$ has $24$ distinct divisors, and as you can see we can easily divide the circle into halves, thirds fourths etc without having to deal with a fractional number of degrees. The exact origin is - to my knowledge - unknow, but this seems to be one reasonable reason.

This is also why we have still systems of units that may seem strange (strange meaning not base 10), but that are quite useful for everyday life: 24 hours per day, 60 minutes per hour etc.

But there are also other conventions, depending on what area you need your measurement of angle in, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_unit

Comment: Don't forget that a year has, by pure coincidence, about 360 days.  This results in early astronomers studying the circular orbit or earth (or at least the effects of a presumed circular orbit of the sun) in increments of daily angles of about 1 degree.

Comment: Another fun thing is that astronomers also use a spherical coordinate system for the sky objects, where the *right ascension* (longitude) is measured in 24 hours. This also works out *almost* too, when considering the rotation of earth.

Comment: Exactly.  And when you divide a degree into sixtieths we call it a minute (and one minute of latitude on the globe is exactly 1 nautical mile) and we divide *that* into sixtieths we call the seconds.  And *why* does a day have 24 hours? And an hour have 60 minutes.  Because 24 goes into 360 nicely so you can associate the hours with the angular position of the stars and sun.  And it *all* boils down to: 360 is easy to divide and 360 is almost equal to the days in the year.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you assume 360 degrees has any significance whatsoever?

It doesn't.

But we have have to give it *some* value.

360 being divisible by not just 2,3,4,5 and 12 but also 8 and 9 is extremely versatile and useful.

Also, by coincidence, in astronomical/astrological and celestial navigation purposes, a year having roughly 360 days (a pure coincidence) would have convenience and (incorrectly) presumed significance.

Answer (score 0):

The Sumerians and Babylonians used a Sexagesimal (base $60$) numeral system. When  an object or quantity, such as the radius of a circle, was subdivided, it was typically broken into $60$ equal parts. Euclid IV.$15$ shows that if the circumference of a circle is divided into $6$ equal arcs, the points of division are the vertices of a regular hexagon whose sides are congruent to the radius of the circle. Since the radius is divided into $60$ parts, or degrees, each side of the hexagon also has $60$ degrees and a complete trip around the circle will pass through $6\times60$, or $360$ degrees.